# There's a good fellow [Phrase]

Tags: phrases, british-english

I would like to learn more about the meaning of the phrase: There's a good fellow. All that I know is that it is used for praising or encouraging a child or an animal. Is it right?

Comment: What part of the phrase is confusing? It's a straight-forward sentence.

Comment: This is a very good question. The expression usually follows a request. 'Stop swinging from the chandelier, there's a good fellow'. I have always assumed it means 'If you stop wiping your nose on the curtains (or any other outrageous behaviour in which you routinely engage) you will be worthy to be pointed out - 'there is a good fellow'. But I am happy to stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, it performs the same role in discourse as the phrase "if you don't mind": The point of it is to indicate that the person speaking isn't ill-disposed toward the person being addressed and doesn't wish to come across as dictatorial, and yet is serious about having that person cooperate with the requested action.

The problem is that, without the softening phrase, the framing of the requested action sounds very much like a command. So the speaker is trying to maintain a delicate balance between amicability and imperative voice—at least in the OP's example ("Cut out cheap wit and listen to me, there's a good fellow") and in WS2's example ("Stop swinging from the chandelier, there's a good fellow").

I share WS2's interpretation of the words "there's a good fellow" under these circumstances as being something along the lines of "By performing the action I request, you will be acting the part of a good fellow, and will qualify for pointing out as such."

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's correct; you're stating a fact. There is [pointing something out] a good fellow [the thing]. Setting aside the attached meaning of the phrase for a minute, grammatically it's no different than saying "There's a good restaurant", or "That's a nice toy-truck".

The phrase "There's a good fellow" goes back to the idea of being a "good man". It's used generally for referring to someone younger or beneath the speaker. It suggests that what they are currently doing is approved of, and such actions will lead to him becoming a "good man".

It can also be a method of exerting control over someone, because generally speaking people like receiving approval. A similar phrase is "that's a good man" which is often followed by "you're doing the right thing". In this case approval, and re-assurance are used aid someone in doing something they have alternative feelings towards.

(I have no sources or examples supporting my statements so I'm making it a community wiki in the hopes that others will improve it. You can help by adding examples, citations, and correcting mistakes.)

Comment: I understand the meaning of "There's a good fellow" when used as a statement, similar to "There's a good restaurant"and etc. the point here is to understand this phrase when used not as a statement, but like this: "Cut out cheap wit and listen to me, there's a good fellow. I'm in a real difficulty".

Answer (score -1):

This phrase is generally used when someone helps you out in your work,and you praise him by using this phrase.Its not generally used by modern speakers.